# TextFormField enter key press getting setState() called during build -error

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am trying to add some values from TextFormField to ListView when click on enter key .
But getting the error     setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

My code is below .

```
    class ScanBarcode extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
   _ScanBarcodeState createState() => _ScanBarcodeState();
    }
     class _ScanBarcodeState extends State<ScanBarcode> {
   List<String> litems = [];
   final TextEditingController eCtrl = new TextEditingController();

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Dynamic Demo"),),
    body: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextFormField(
          controller: eCtrl,
          maxLines: null,
          autovalidate: true,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.none,

          // ignore: missing_return
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty==false) {
              // if(eCtrl.text.trim()!='') {
              if (value.contains('\n')) {
                debugPrint(value);
                litems.add(value); // Append Text to the list
                eCtrl.clear(); // Clear the Text area
                setState(() {});
              }
            }
            // }
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: 'Enter a search term'
          ),

        ),
        new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder
              (
                itemCount: litems.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                  return new Text(litems[Index]);
                }
            )
        )
      ],
    )
  );
  }
 }
```

I am getting below error.

```
  setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build
```

if commented

```
 setState()
```

it is working fine but the values are not added to list view ..

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `addPostFrameCallback` 
code snippet

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  setState(() {});
                });
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScanBarcode extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScanBarcodeState createState() => _ScanBarcodeState();
}

class _ScanBarcodeState extends State<ScanBarcode> {
  List<String> litems = [];
  final TextEditingController eCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Dynamic Demo"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: eCtrl,
              maxLines: null,
              autovalidate: true,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.none,

              // ignore: missing_return
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty == false) {
                  // if(eCtrl.text.trim()!='') {
                  if (value.contains('\n')) {
                    debugPrint(value);
                    litems.add(value); // Append Text to the list
                    eCtrl.clear(); // Clear the Text area
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      setState(() {});
                    });
                  }
                }
                // }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: litems.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                      return Text(litems[Index]);
                    }))
          ],
        ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ScanBarcode(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Chunhunghan's** solution is a valid solution and still works. But, in my case, it's the future build & the stream builder.

What I did is, I directly assigned the Future to a FutureBuilder, which gets called every time when the build() is called, which causes the Future method to re-call & reload my UI every time I touched/typed on a TextField/TextFormField.

**The Solution:**

Create a Future object & assign the Future method to that future object, then assign the future object to the FutureBuilder widget.

**The Code:**

```
  late Future _dataFuture;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
     _stream = _leadDatabase.listenLeads();
     _dataFuture = _fetchData();
  }
  
  //inside build()
  FutureBuilder(future: _dataFuture, builder:context, dataSnapshot) {
      //logics
  }
```

The same solution is applicable for StreamBuilder.